# Provide access to the volume control via hardware buttons on Lock screen

Tags: android, volume, chromecast

In locked mode, when not casting my app adjusts the media volume but it fails to do so while when I'm casting.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the CastCompanionLibrary (CCL), in VideoCastManager class, to see how it is doing it (assuming you have tested the CastVideos-android and that is doing it as you expect). Are you using RemoteControlClient (RCC)? One thing to try is to register the RCC instance with the AudioManager:

`registerRemoteControlClient(RemoteControlClient rcClient)`

If you look into `setUpRemoteControl(..)` method in [VideoCastManager](https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/blob/master/src/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/VideoCastManager.java) in the CCL project, you should be able to get it to work. Note that this feature is not available on older versions of Android.

Comment: CastCompanionLibrary doesn't use volume buttons handling on RemoteControlClient.

Comment: Yes, it does provide that functionality on supported versions